# Source for stoning a grave

Tags: sources-mekorot, death, cemetery-grave

Although there are sources (Be'er Heitev [OC 224:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.224.12?lang=bi&with=Ba%27er%20Hetev&lang2=en)) which discuss placing stones on a grave, that seems to be more of an honor for the deceased. Apparently Rebbi Akiva Eiger asked his family to stone his grave as an atonement - where do we find such a concept? (And is his will available to view?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Eduyot 5:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Eduyot.5.6?lang=he):

> שֶׁכָּל הַמִּתְנַדֶּה וּמֵת בְּנִדּוּיוֹ סוֹקְלִין אֶת אֲרוֹנוֹ
>
> Anyone who dies in a state of excommunication, we stone his coffin

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Would you happen to know where Rebbi Akiva Eiger uses this concept?

Comment: Sorry. Haven’t come across this story about R Akiva Eger before